# How to clear a Set at Midnight?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a script that receives information from an endpoint, stores this information and counts the number of occurrences in a set.
At 23:59 the size of the set is written to a file and I want the set to be cleared by 00:00(midnight) to recount the number of occurrences the next day.

```
def delayedCounter(delayedSet):
    now = datetime.now()
    date = now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    hour = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')
    with open('delayedData.csv','a+') as file:
        if hour == '23:59':
            file.write(f'Nº : {len(delayedSet)} Data: {date}\n')
        elif hour == '00:00':
            delayedSet.clear()
```

Along with this I am using Flask to display everything in a webapp.
I make the request every 1 minute using apscheduler.
However it writes to the delayedData.csv file but does not reset the set.
Does anyone know what it could be? I can make more code available if  needed

Comment: Add a `print` statement after assigning `hour` and print its value.  Maybe the one minute schedule skips a minute sometimes (runs at 23:59:57 and the next time at 00:01:02 which is roughly one minute apart).

Comment: i guess it worked and i didnt changed anything. this running in localhost. when i run in my VPS simply doest not work like this and writes 3 times in delayedData.csv